# Ubuntu One behind a proxy, how to make it work?

Tags: security, ubuntu-one, proxy, networking

I am behind a web proxy server at work (no authentication) and I have set it up in Gnome (configuration applied system-wide).

It works fine for accessing internet with a browser, but numerous applications do not make use of this setting (**Empathy**, **Gwibber** or **Ubuntu One** to say a few) and cannot connect.

[image]
The question here will be specific to Ubuntu One which is for me more critical.

**How did you manage to connect to Ubuntu One when behind a proxy?** The easiest solution will be preferred ;-)

Have you used some tools to tunnel the data? *Corkscrew*? *Proxychains*? If you have done that sucessfully can you share your experience and configuration instructions?

Note: for those interested, here is the [Ubuntu One bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/387308).

*The Ubuntu One is currently (20111031) conducting a user survey on the topic of proxy access. If you are also behind a proxy, please fill up their survey to help them address this problem: [Ubuntu One Tweet for User Survey](https://twitter.com/#!/UbuntuOne/status/131043831088029696).*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of the version 3 of the Ubuntu One client (currently in 12.04, soon to be released for Windows and backported to older Ubuntu versions), connecting through a proxy should work in most situations. In Ubuntu you need to ensure `ubuntuone-client-proxy` is installed (it isn’t installed by default), and proxy settings should be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, some parts of Ubuntu One (i.e. Tomboy notes) should already work behind a proxy, but unfortunately not the most important part, file sync.

I've come across a number of work-a-rounds for this via the [ubuntu-one-users listserve.](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-users/) The most promising one seems to be [this wiki entry](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RomanYepishev/UbuntuOne/ProxySupport). It requires the installation of the `connect-proxy` package and a manual edit of your `~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` file.

Alan Pope has another work-a-round in [this blog post](http://popey.com/blog/2010/02/25/proxies-in-the-way-of-testing/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have to say until this is fixed, you are better off using Dropbox which work's perfectly behind a proxy.

This feature is really needed, and it is a big surprise having tried to just connect from behind a proxy that it hasn't been in the utility from day one.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work on Ubuntu 11.10 - Ubuntu One client version 2.0.0.

Did the following:

1. Set the HTTP proxy in network proxy settings (Apply system wide)

   ```
   sudo vim /usr/share/pyshared/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone/syncdaemon/action_queue.py
   ```
2. Changed the line "from urlparse import urljoin" to "from urlparse import urljoin, urlparse"
3. Added the line "from ubuntuone.storageprotocol.proxy_tunnel import ProxyTunnelFactory" right below the line "from ubuntuone.storageprotocol.context import get_ssl_context"
4. Changed the following: http://pastebin.com/avKHcWeS

   ```
   sudo vim /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol/ubuntuone/storageprotocol/proxy_tunnel.py
   ```
5. Changed the following: http://pastebin.com/XTSu9Hbg

Answer (score 0):

In the network proxy settings (System > Preferences > Network Proxy) after you enter your proxy, hit Apply System-Wide.

It should work, I never tried it, but I remember fixing such an issue with my friend.

Comment: Nope it does not work. I had already this setup (though with an automatic proxy configuration script) and applied system wide. I've just tried to configure the proxy manually and applying it also system wide with the same results. See the bug report, it is not fixed even in 10.10.

Comment: Yeah I just saw the report, that must suck pretty bad! Thank god I don't have a proxy on my network =)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a known bug and people are working on it. The easiest way is to wait for someone to release a patch and that this patch is integrated in a update.

Comment: Someone in the bug report was mentioning proxychains. I know there is also corkscrew. Both are utilities to access the internet via a proxy or firewall even if the application does not support it. I'm hoping someone has details instructions on how to use this tools (or another) to access Ubuntu One.