# Can't sync with Ubuntu One through a proxy server

Tags: ubuntu-one, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One behind a proxy, how to make it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7081/ubuntu-one-behind-a-proxy-how-to-make-it-work)

I have been using Ubuntu since 8.04. The problem is that with every new release, Ubuntu One seems not to work in my network. I use a campus network meaning that I connect to the Internet via a proxy server. Please help since Ubuntu One seems not to resolve proxies...

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the current version doesn't have proxy support. It is the first item in our task list, though!

So, we are working on it, and you can keep yourself posted about it by following this bug in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/387308

Comment: Thank you. look forward to enjoying Ubuntu 1 on my lovely ubuntu netbook