# Ubuntu One can't sync folders through authenticated proxy

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, sync, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One behind a proxy, how to make it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7081/ubuntu-one-behind-a-proxy-how-to-make-it-work)

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I can connect my account to Ubuntu One. But I can't sync the folders to my account.

Whenever I open the ubuntu one desktop client, it appears "File sync is starting" at the right top corner.  Then after two minutes, "File sync is disconnected".

I am behind a proxy that requires a user name and password.

Comment: Hi there. It seems this _File can't sync_ issue in Ubuntu One isn't too uncommon, and many similar questions (& hopefully answers) can be found by using the search feature on AskUbuntu. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you install ubuntuone-client-proxy and configure your proxy settings in Network Manager.

Comment: Thank you very much Roberto Alsina.After installing ubuntuone-client-proxy,It just worked.Really you saved my hours of time.