# Can not authenticate in Ubuntu One behind a proxy

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, proxy

After installing it at home without any problem, I'm trying to install Ubuntu One at work (Ubuntu 12.04, must use proxy). Apparently it can not connect to the server: I can't sign in of course, can't use the "forgotten password" form either (address not recognized), and if I open the dialog to create an account I get a message "There was a problem downloading the captcha, reloading...".

I tried installing `ubuntuone-client-proxy`: 
[Ubuntu One behind a proxy, how to make it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7081/ubuntu-one-behind-a-proxy-how-to-make-it-work)

and resinstalling the certificates:
https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-am-i-getting-an-the-authentication-failed-error-on-windows-225/

... without any success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question in
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12377799#post12377799
but didn't get any answer either. turns out that it's apparently impossible to use Ubuntu One with my proxy configuration (see details in the link).